# SSRS Optional Filter For Null Values

Tags: reporting-services

I am building a SSRS report that will have around 60K rows of data each month run; of those rows there are two categories that will only be populated in about 1K rows, but are of great importance to the end users.

My goal would be to have an Optional Filter for users to utilize; if the checkbox/boolean is selected for the category, then only show rows where that category IS NOT NULL, else show all rows.

I'm thinking my code would be something like this:

```
Select * 
From Table 
Where IF (Parameter1='True', Category1 IS NOT NULL, "Show All Rows")
```

Obviously that code isn't correct, but I hope it gives an idea of what I'm looking for.

Thank you for assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boolean logic in your `WHERE` clause to return true when no parameter value is set.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
  Table
WHERE
 ((@Category1 IS NULL)OR(Table.Category=@Category1))
```